# three.js 3D plane to 2D

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Given is a THREE.Mesh in 3D space which is actually a flat plane: 
[Screenshot of Rooftop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coDzt.png)
The Vertices of the Geometry are e.g. 
[ 0 ] x=-9.364500045776367,  y=-4.42410278320267,  z=7.22250041179359
[ 1 ] x=2.948499954305589,  y=-2.273284912108636,  z=4.937500411877409
[ 2 ] x=-7.154500045347959,  y=4.424102783203352,  z=-8.842499588150531
[ 3 ] x=2.412499954458326,  y=-4.42410278320267,  z=8.842500411905348
[ 4 ] x=9.364499954506755,  y=4.424102783203352,  z=-6.5714995882008225
[ 5 ] x=7.691499954555184,  y=-2.273284912108636,  z=5.589500411879271

How can I reduce the 3D coordinates to 2D so that the rooftop can be drawn on in 2D space (to add a rectangle and so on) ?

**What I tried:**
 
Rotating the Geometry like

```
geometry2.rotateX( - geometry2.faces[0].normal.angleTo(  new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0)  ));
geometry2.rotateZ( - geometry2.faces[0].normal.angleTo(  new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0)  ));
```

Unfortunately still a slight angle remains so that thy y-coordinates afterwards are not equal.

Comment: Simplest Way: Just use the corner points (0,1,4,5 I think) and convert that to a rectangle/2D plane. If you intend to keep the same area, then that will be a little more difficult

Comment: Unfortunantely that doesn't work since the mesh isn't a rectangle but can be anything like the screenshot I have added above. The corners have not necessarily 90° angles.